# Is there an analog to Angular secondary routes in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes, angular-ui-router, ionic2

everyone!

We're building an app that's going to work both as a web page and an app. So far we used ionic navigation, but for the next phase of the production, the flow was completely rebuilt. Most of the views are still fine, but there are some pages with secondary routes and breadcrumbs like this on a screenshot:

**App prototype**

[image]

In angular making such routes is not a problem, but what about ionic? If it was just mobile app Deeplinks would be more than enough, but it doesn't seem to support secondary routes and that is important for a web page. Does anyone have any ideas on how to make it all work?

So far, we're using Ionic 3.0.1 and Angular 4, trying to keep the build on the latest tech. Feel free to ask any questions.

Any help or thoughts are welcome!
Dmytro